# A finite language of chains is TM decidable?

Tags: turing-machines, turing-recognizable

In class we were talking about the decidability and acceptability of languages by Turing Machines but a doubt arose in my mind, "is any language containing a finite number of strings decidable by Turing Machines?"
My first answer could be no, since there are finite languages that are undecidable.

Comment: Can you give an example of a finite language that is undecidable?

Comment: I think no but I can’t see why? @Steven